# Sorting algorithm of only two different elements

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I'm stuck with relatively simple sorting problem. I have to write a method `sort_points(Point[] points)` that sorts a `Point` array based only the `Point`s `x` coordinates; and it is known that their `x` coordinates can only be either `1` or `2`. Their `y` coordinates are irrelevant; and I cannot use extra arrays to help.

For example, the following

```
{(1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2)}
```

should become this

```
{(1, 3), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1)}
```

after sorting.

The challenging part is that I have to sort in time complexity of O(array.length), which (correct me if I'm wrong) means that I have to sort the array in one iteration of initial point array.

My initial idea was to append any `points` element where `x` is `2` to the end of the array, but that means deleting an element in the array while at the same time iterating over it, which gives a lot of problems in Java.

Can anyone suggest how to approach this?

Comment: Should the sorting be stable? If not you can simply swap current element with some element from end. You need to maintain 2 indices: current left position and current right position. And loop `while( left + right < points.length)`

Comment: You are wrong in your understanding of Big O. What `O(n)` means is not a _single_ iteration, but a _constant number_ of iterations. As long as you don't nest any loops, it's all `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks for corrections @Iealand. Now I get it! My understanding in Big-O is somewhat bad, and I was wondering what O(n) means in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep two indices: **i** (to be used to iterate over the array), and **j** (to be used to mark the boundary between the 2's and the 1's). Set j to point to the end of the array, and iterate with i from 0 to j.

If the value at i is a 2 then swap it with the value at j, and then decrement j (to move the boundary one index to the left). If a swap was performed, check to see if a 2 was swapped for a 2, and if so then decrement i (since the same index will need to be examined again in the next iteration).

Example code..

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2};

int j = a.length-1;
for (int i=0; i<j; i++)
{
    if (a[i] == 2)
    {
        int tmp = a[i];         // swap a[i] and a[j]
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = tmp;

        j--;

        if (a[i] == 2)
            i--;
    }
}
```

Example run:

```
Let a = {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2}

i = 0; j = 5;    1 2 1 1 2 2      
                 i         j
                                  i++

i = 1; j = 5;    1 2 1 1 2 2
                   i       j      a[i] == 2 ... swap a[i] w/ a[j]; j--
                                  a[i] == 2; i--; 
                                  i++

i = 1; j = 4     1 2 1 1 2 2
                   i     j        a[i] == 2 ... swap a[i] w/ a[j]; j--
                                  a[i] == 2; i--; 
                                  i++

i = 1; j = 3     1 2 1 1 2 2      a[i] == 2 ... swap a[i] w/ a[j]; j--
                   i   j          
                                  i++  

i = 2; j = 3     1 1 1 2 2 2
                   i j
                                  i++

i = 3; j = 3     1 1 1 2 2 2
                     i
                     j
```

Comment: Accepted. Your implementation and explanation really helped me.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem in O(n) time without deleting or appending array elements.  Try something along these lines:

Keep track of two indexes, the current point being checked (`curr`) and the first occurrence of X = 2. (`first_two`)  Start at index 0 and continue to increment `curr` and `first_two` until you find an X = 2 for the first time.  Save this index as `first_two` and then continue to increment `curr`.  When you come across the next X = 1, swap it with the data at index `first_two`, increment `first_two` by 1, and continue.

Here's a rundown with your example:

```
{(1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2)}
  c
  f

{(1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2)}
          c
          f

{(1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2)}
                  c
          f

{(1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2)}
                          c
          f
```

SWAP and increment f

```
{(1, 3), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2)}
                          c
                  f

{(1, 3), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2)}
                                  c
                  f
```

Another swap and increment

```
{(1, 3), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1)}
                                  c
                  f
```

All Done!

There are some edge cases you'll have to account for but these are the basics of an O(n) solution to your problem.

Comment: I was trying to crack down the implementation of your algorithm and found similarities between your answer and @trooper. Really helped me to understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Try this algorithm:

```
while (true) {
    while (j > i && array[j].getX() == 2)
        j--;
    while (i < j && array[i].getX() == 1)
        i++;
     if (j <= i)
        break;
     Point aux;
     aux = array[i];
     array[i] = array[j];
     array[j] = aux;
     i++;
     j--;
}
```

It certainly isn't pretty, but I think it fulfills the requirements.

Comment: That's the problem I can't have any nested for/while loops, because then it's not in `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to do it in one iteration. Since x can only be 1 or 2, you can first search for the first occurrence of x=2 and then simply maintain the position where the x-values jump from 1 to 2 and switch elements when necessary.

```
int[] x = {1,2,2,1,1};
int[] y = {3,2,1,1,2};
int n = x.length;

// Search position of first point with x=2.
int index = -1;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    if (x[i]==2) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
// If no point has x=2 the list is already sorted.
if (index==-1) return;

// Loop over the rest and switch points if x=1 occurs.
for (int i=index+1;i<n;i++) {
    if (x[i]==1) {
       x[i] = 2;
       x[index] = 1;
       int temp = y[index];
       y[index] = y[i];
       y[i] = temp;
       index++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible to sort in time complexity of O(n) with n is the size of the array by using the comparison sorting. This is because the lower bound for comparison sorting is O(n*log(n)).

If knowledge of the data to be sorted is known (in your case array based only the Points x coordinates; and it is known that their x coordinates can only be either 1 or 2), then **radix sorting** can be used. In this case the time complexity can be O(n). However, an extra array will be needed.

This link may be useful for you: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/radix-sort/

In you case it is even simpler:  after sorting by least significant digit of x coordinates you can stop.

Answer (score -2):

Use This Code,The java.util.Collections.sort() method use the best algo for sorting:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;


class Point implements Comparable<Point>{
private int x,y;

public int getX() {return x;}
public void setX(int x) {this.x = x;}

public int getY() {return y;}
public void setY(int y) {this.y = y;}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return"("+x+","+y+")";
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Point o) {
    if(this.x==o.x)
        return 0;
    else
        if(this.x>o.x)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;


}

}

public class SortPoint {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Point>sortedPoints=new ArrayList<Point>();

    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        Point p=new Point();
        p.setX(in.nextInt());
        p.setY(in.nextInt());
        sortedPoints.add(p);
    }
    in.close();
    Collections.sort(sortedPoints);
    System.out.print(sortedPoints);
}
```

}

```
Provide Input as:
1 3
2 2
2 1
1 1
1 2
```

You'll get desired output.

Comment: `Collections.sort()` uses a merge sort which has a worst case of O(n log n).  The output will be correct but this fails to meet the requirements of the problem's need for an O(n) solution.